# 400 Error POST Method to DynamoDB - AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to update a DynamoDB table with information that I add into a HTML form. Every time that I run my program and submit my information, I get this error:

> POST https://quovje1gi8.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/accounts 400 ()

I can run my Lambda function on AWS, and add data to my table just fine. I have checked again and again to make sure that my permissions are established correctly and they are. I just can't seem to figure this out.

My front-end:

```
<form>
<label for="username">Add Username:</label>
<textarea id="username"></textarea>

<button id='submitButton'>Submit</button>
</form>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var API_URL = 'https://quovje1gi8.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/accounts';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: API_URL,

        success: function(data){
            $('#accounts').html('');

            data.Items.forEach(function(accountsItem){
                $('#accounts').append('<p>' + accountsItem.username + '</p>');
            })
        }
   });
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: API_URL,
        data: JSON.stringify({"username": $('#username').val()}),
        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function(data){
            location.reload();
        }
   });

    return false;

});
```

Lambda function:

```
'use strict';

console.log('Starting Function');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-east-2'});

exports.handler = function(e, ctx, callback) {

var params = {
    Item: {
        user_id: ,
        date: Date.now(),
        username: "",
        password: "",
        name: "",
        location: "",
        field: "",
        company: ""
    },

    TableName: 'accounts'
};

docClient.put(params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err, null);
    }
    else{
        callback(null, data);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you have [CORS enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?

Comment: CORS is enabled. I completely restarted my API Gateway from scratch, several times in the attempt to see if I've made a mistake and I have the same result every time.